# display the 'ping' output to the browser using child_process

Tags: node.js, child-process

How can I Stream the output of the ping to the browser asynchronously, The child_process.spawn() is an async call. But how do I pipe the process to the browser/html ? Any suggestions ?

Here is the code

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var ping = spawn('ping',['www.google.com'],
    { stdio: ['pipe', process.stdout, process.stderr] });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Express](http://expressjs.com), `res` is stremable

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var ping = spawn('ping', ['www.google.com']);
    ping.stdout.pipe(res);
});
```

BTW, there's a [`ping`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping) module too.